# Difference between createTempview and createGlobaltempview and CreateorReplaceTempview in spark 2.1?

Tags: apache-spark, temp-tables, global-temp-tables

What is the difference between `createTempview` and `createGlobaltempview` and `CreateorReplaceTempview` in spark 2.1 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Global Temporary View**

As per [documentation](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#global-temporary-view), global temporary view are views that are shared among all the sessions, untill all the Spark Application terminates.

**createorReplaceTempview**

`createTempView` (or more appropriately `createOrReplaceTempView`) has been introduced in Spark 2.0 to replace `registerTempTable`, which has been deprecated in 2.0. `createTempView` creates an in memory reference to the `Dataframe` in use. The lifetime for this is tied to the spark session in which the `Dataframe` was created in